# jquery select and exclude multiple nth-childs

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, css-selectors

Is there a way that i can select multiple nth-childs at once like:

```
    $("#table").find("tr > :not(td:nth-child(1,3,5))");
```

which doesn't work

I want to select all td in each row but not for column 1,3,5 (this can be any combination).

Is there a way to do this? I cannot assign classnames.

thanks for any help!

UPDATE:

I want to search in all rows of a table, but exclude some columns.

I have this code right now:

```
    elem.keyup(function() {

    $(options.table).find("tr").hide();
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    var jo = $(options.table).find("tr > :not(td:nth-child("+cols+"))");

    $.each(data, function(i, v){

    jo = jo.filter(":containsIgnoreCase('"+v+"')");

    });

    jo.parent().show();
    });
```

It works when I pass a single value, but i want to exclude multiple columns.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it looks like you're trying to exclude the odd numbers. Try:

```
$("#table").find("tr > :not(td:nth-child(odd))");
```

Although, it may be more efficient to just select the even ones.

```
$("#table").find("tr > td:nth-child(even)");
```

You can also use formulas in nth-child. [See this link for more detail.](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

Okay, as per comments below/clarification on the question, here is another solution.

```
$("#table").find("tr > td").filter(function(index){
   return index == 1 || index == 2 || index == 5;   
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but no, this was just a bad example. it can be column 1,7,8, or 4,6...

Comment: how are you determining which columns are to be excluded? Or are you hard-coding each time?

Comment: the columns are hardcoded, i will use that for a inline-table search for many different tables and always have to exclude some colums.., my example works when i have just one column to exclude, but i won't work for multiple columns

Comment: can you please explain me how i can integrate that into this: var jo = $(options.table).find("tr > td");
                $.each(data, function(i, v){
  
                    jo = jo.filter(":containsIgnoreCase('"+v+"')");
                   
                 });

Comment: again, edited above. If you have any additions to your question, I suggest you edit the actual question, or start a new one (instead of elaborating in the comments here). Thanks.

Comment: thank you very much, but i don't get it... edited my first post